# How to sort Git tags in groovy?

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to fetch all git tags in descending order via groovy script.
I am using below commands in my script.

> def gettagsUrl = "git ls-remote --tags https://" + bitbucketUser + ":" + bitbucketPass +"bitbucket/scm/config/configurations-" + "Object" +".git" +"|" + command
>
> def command = ['#!/bin/bash', '-c' , sort -Vr -k2 ]

But I am getting below error:-

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sort for
> class: Script1    at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)

My git version is 1.8.3.1

Can anyone help here. TIA

Comment: quotes around `sort ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this version
Groovy scripts work for me for fetching tag

```
def gettagsUrl =[ "/bin/bash","-c" , "git ls-remote https://" + bitbucketUser + ":" + bitbucketPass
+"bitbucket/scm/config/configurations-" + "Object" +".git" | awk '{print \$2}' | grep -v '\\^{}\$' | sort -r -V | sed 's@refs/tags/@@' " ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `git tag` command has an option to sort tags as version numbers :

```
git tag --sort="version:refname"
```

all the details can be read [in the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt---sortltkeygt)

Comment: This git versions is not support sort tag

Comment: The question says it wants the versions in descending order ("I am trying to fetch all git tags in descending order").  I think you should include a `-` sign before `version` as `git tag --sort="-version:refname"`.